Is it safe run blocking call in OS executor when using virtual thread?
When using virtual thread, can I safely use a separate thread pool while interacting with a library we don't have a control over, such as HikariCP DB connection manager, which uses synchronized blocks, does not support virtual threads, and is not yet ready for them?
For example, the getHikariConnection method below is called by virtual thread.
private val hikarliExecutor = Executors.newWorkStealingPool() // or new FixedPool
def getHikariConnection(prams: String) = {
    var conn: Connection = null
    val rstFuture = hikarliExecutor.submit(
      new Runnable {
        override def run(): Unit = {
          conn = getConnection()
        }
      },
      conn
    )

    rstFuture.get()
  }


  private def getConnection(): Connection = {
    // call hikariCP API get a connection
    val conn = ...

    return conn
  }

I am not aware of design principles and guidelines in respect of this pattern and would like to know opinions on that.
In respect of HikariCP, I have two specific questions:

Will it be safe to use separate thread executor with existing virtual thread?
What would be impact of such design on performance? Would it make a sense to implement virtual thread-based DB connection manager pool?


You should use the virtual thread executors everywhere -- not newWorkStealingPool -- and as long as you do that, then you should block as much as you want without any restrictions.  You no longer need to worry about blocking or non blocking executors.

Do not Close please.hi, @LouisWasserman. In my case, I can't control others library using virtual thread. But I still want using such library.

The usage of Executors.newWorkStealingPool, in fact ForkJoinPool, makes no sense in this scenario because virtual threads already use FJP "under the hood". Virtual thread executors are discussed here and in many other recent SO threads. You could improve your question if you streamline your statements and make them readable, then it would be possible to apply for reopening,

If you don't control the library, then nothing changes at all.  No virtual threads, no benefits.

@LouisWasserman, doesn't it depend on how "bad" this 3-rd party library is and what is exactly wrong with it in respect of virtual threads? Bad is, IMHO, so wide of a definition... LoranceChen, is there any way to learn what library is this and look at it? Could you point  at its relevant classes?

the library I meet such as HikariCP. I need pool to manage DB connections. But it haven't support virtual thread yet. Does this example make sense? I'm also finding lib for redis and kafka too. I hope every one use virtual thread but java have it's history actually. Solve the problem is first consider and wait to migrate best step by step.

Yes, this makes perfect sense. Yes, AFAIK, HikariCP does not use virtual threads. Then why did you call it "bad" library? If a library does not use virtual threads, it does not necessarily makes it bad. What could make it (relatively) bad, is a usage of Java intrinsic monitor (synchronized). Did you mean that?

yeah. I will clarify this point in the topic later.

Thanks for clarification and sorry for the delay. I tried to edit your question according to my understanding, but SO didn't allow me to do it. If I succeed with editing you could review my version and edit correspondingly. I got an impression that your question is valid and interesting, but not very well formulated.

Thanks @igor.zh. I edit and the post is reviewing. Hope you able to review and edit it again. It's great if can remove Closed status.

Great. I've edited your question a bit, now my edit will be reviewed by SO men. Few things in your question are still not clear for me, e.g. getHikariConnection method get executed in a virtual thread or executes its Runnable in a VT, but let's begin with basics. My edit would be very likely turned down because of my low rep, if so we should think of further strategy.

It looks like my edit went through (surprisingly enough). Please review my edit and let me know if I have distorted your initial intentions. Please also fell free to edit what I have distorted. Once this is mitigated, we could apply for reopening.

@igor.zh it's good. thanks

I requested a reopening a day before yesterday, but it hasn't yet been reviewed. Let us wait for SO verdict.

@igor.zh The edit does not add information that is relevant to the question.
